# Why are my Vista directories visible to other machines on wifi networks?

Tags: windows-vista, security

I log on to various Wifi networks with my Vista laptop. The problem is, the other computers can view my Public (and any shared) directories, even though I have chosen Public Location when I logged on. Normal Windows Firewall is on.

This doesn't happen on my XP laptop using the same wifi networks - nothing is viewable on that, even the Public folders.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727037.aspx):

Configuring File and Printer Sharing Behavior in Windows Vista

Configuring file and printer sharing behavior in Windows Vista consists of the following:

- Setting the workgroup name to be the same as the other computers
- Setting the network location type
- Enabling file and printer sharing options

So I'm guessing you have the options enabled and the computers which can see your shares have the same workgroup name.

If not, there is a chance that you have a compromised machine - some malware shuts down security options.

Comment: But if I turn off File And Printer Sharing, then other users on my office network cannot access my files (and I want them to be able to).
When I log on to wireless networks and set it to a Public location, it is supposed to turn off File And Printer Sharing for that wireless connection, isn't it? But it doesn't seem to.
In the meantime, I have installed the free ZoneAlarm and that seems to make it as secure as I need it to be, yet I can allow my usual network to still work. I'd prefer not to rely on ZoneAlarm, though.

Comment: @mish why not rely on a firewall to do firewalling? That is exactly what it is for.